# Pass objective C NSMutable array pointer to SwiftUI VIew

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that gets passed an objective C class instance. This objective c class has a member that is a pointer to an NSMutablearray of pointers to an objective c class I made. Objects are added to this NSMutable array periodically as packets are captured in a background thread. I would like a ScrollView to render as many items as there are packets in this NSMutablearray. At the moment, I initilize the SwiftUI views member in the constructor as such

```
init (device : PcapCppDevWrapper, captureWindowIsOpen: Binding <Bool>) {
        self.aDevice = device
        self.packets = device.getPacketArray() as! [PcapCppPacketWrappper]
        self._captureWindowIsOpen = captureWindowIsOpen
    }
```

As it stands, even though I can clearly see the NSMutableArray in the Obj C class count increasing in the debugger as packets are added, the "packets" variable in the swiftUI view doesn't expand in size whatsoever. How do I make the swiftui array "mirror" the NSMutablearray contained within the obj c class? Replies are appreciated

Comment: This sounds like an uphill battle! Maybe use KVO? And then update a Combine Publisher based on the changes?

Comment: guessing SwiftUI is still running in mainThread and your captured packets filled in the background thread may be valid but will not show up correctly unless you force back to mainThread again. And ask yourself how is the UI knowing there new objects to show.. Notification? KVO? Delegate? dispatch_wait

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that an `Array` in Swift is a *value type*, not a *reference type* while `NSMutableArray` is a reference type.

So any variable that references the `NSMutableArray` will see changes that are done to that object.  If you have two variables and assign the same Swift array to them, then for all intents and purposes they each have a separate array.

When you do your casting, you're capturing a snapshot of the mutable array, and that snapshot is no longer associated with the Objective-C Array.

In this case, it looks like you **want** the reference semantics of the `NSMutableArray`.  There's no reason you have to copy the data out into a Swift Array.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, as when I observed the swift view's array value right after the initializer is called, it was an array of zero, but if I printed the result of device.getPacketArray() when I stopped packet capture, it would clearly print out many memory addresses of the packet objects within said array.

Comment: Remember that a Swift Array (a value type) can contain a bunch of references to objects.  Because they are references, if the objects they refer to change, then you will see that change through the reference stored in the array.  (It's a little confusing)

Comment: Changing the array to an NSMutable array fixed the issue of the array not updating, but I have run into a new issue; I want to render as many items (yet to decide what those items will be )as there are packets in the NSMutableArray. This issue is I can't seem to use the NSMutable in a ForEach() loop in swifui, & if I downcast it to an NSArray it complains that "generic struct ForEach requires that NSObject conform to Random access collection".